# Image strategy on Android

Tags: android, json, image

I am creating an application with lots of photos. They will take `> 100 mb` on memory. So far I have 3 ideas:

> 1. Place it in `@drawable`  - app will be heavy
> 2. Download by JSON and place in java array - cashing - How long it can be there?
> 3. Download by JSON, place it on phone memory/SD card and read in application from memory. User can Remove pictures.

The best option will be to give possibility to user if he want to have a pictures or not.

What strategy is most efficient and recommended? 
Every opinion and tutorial will be helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: Have you only listed 3 ideas?

Comment: yes, yes. Question has  been edited

Comment: It really depends on the use case. Will your user need to instantly view the images? Will the list of images change?

Comment: I would choose option three, and if you don't want user to delete pictures out of application(via gallery etc.) you can place them encoded or you can place them into one single file, even a database would do the thing. Besides, AFAIK the files who are saved into app directory are not accessible by other apps(except rooted phones) or even by gallery. In addition, if the user might have ability to choose if he wants to keep the images, then let him choose what to do(keep or delete(option 3 or 2) ).

Comment: That will be pictures gallery like one second image: [here link](https://raw.github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/master/UniversalImageLoader.png) and like on 3 pictures.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of library that do the work of downloading the images from web and then cache them in your preferred memory for you. Some of them would be:

**1.** nostra13 / Android-Universal-Image-Loader

**2.** Square / Picasso

**3.** Google / Volle

I wrote a blog post on this subject that you can check:

[How to load images asynchronously into a ListView](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=952)

Comment: In description I see, that I can use `Android-Iniversal_Image_Loader` also as I described in 1 point

Comment: @Serafins, what? I didn't understand you.

Comment: Using `Android-Iniversal_Image_Loader` can I download picture by JSON, save it on memory and then load to view?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Android Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it can also cache the images for you to prevent re-downloads in the future. It has many other features also.

Easy to use too, can load an image from a url into a view by simply using:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Comment: Because I hadn't refreshed the page and was already at the bottom ready to comment...

Comment: You wrote this in 15 minutes?

Comment: No I left it open as a tab, went downstairs, got some tea and a banana, sent a text then came back upstairs to write a short answer. That's about 15 minutes.